# Cant get my c++ program to add at the end.

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my program to add all the switch case inputs. When running it, I get it to ask me to input a Case# ((1-4) and any other number than those 4 will give you an error code) while keeping a log of the inputs generated. However, when I want to end it with a (-1) it just stops working as oppose of giving me a summary of all the registered inputs i have given. This is what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int paycode = 0;
double weeklySalary, hourlySalary, grossSales, payPerItem, totalPay;
int hours, items;

cout << "Enter paycode for employee (-1 to end): ";
cin >> paycode;

while (paycode != -1)
{
    switch (paycode)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter weekly salary for manager: ";
            cin >> weeklySalary;
            totalPay = weeklySalary;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter hourly salary for hourly worker: ";
            cin >> hourlySalary;
            cout << "Enter number of hours worked: ";
            cin >> hours;
            if (hours <= 40)
                totalPay = hours * hourlySalary;
            else
                totalPay = 40 * hourlySalary + (hours - 40) * hourlySalary * 1.5;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Enter gross sales for comission worker: ";
            cin >> grossSales;
            totalPay = 250 + grossSales * 0.057;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Enter number of produced items for pieceworker: ";
            cin >> items;
            cout << "Enter pay for each item: ";
            cin >> payPerItem;
            totalPay = items * payPerItem;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong input!" << endl;
            totalPay = 0;
            break;              
    }
    cout    << setiosflags(ios::fixed);
    cout    << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);
    cout    << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Total weekly pay is: $ " << totalPay << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter paycode for next employee (-1 for exit): ";
    cin >> paycode;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are tracking your inputs. Use an [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to accumulate your inputs.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PaulRooney. Could you explain what you mean by no code. How could I fix it?.

Comment: You have shown us some code and described some functionality. The code and the description don't seem to match up. You are saying that after the loop ends that it should print something. After the loop ends there is no code there except `return 0;`. I would have expected to see your loop store each entry in a container e.g. `vector` and after the loop, iterate over the container and print its contents. Or am I missing something?

Comment: First thing define some `struct` or `class` to hold the details of one entry (hours, employee type, pay etc) and declare a vector of these. When each entry is made populate one these structs and add it to the vector. At the end iterate over the vector and print out its contents.